# Converting string data from an array of data arranged in columns

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert a string array that is itself a part of another array fed into Java from an external file.

There are two parts to this question:

1. How do I convert the string's substring elements to doubles or ints?
2. How do I skip the header which is itself a part of the string?

I have the following piece of code that is NOT giving me an error but neither is it giving me output.  The data is arranged in columns, so as far as the split, I'm not sure what  delimiter to use as the argument for that method.  I've tried `\r, \n, ",", " "` and nothing works.

```
str0 = year.split(",");                         
year = year.trim();                         
int[] yearData = new int[str0.length-1];

for(i = 0; i < str0.length-1; i++) {
    yearData[i] = Integer.parseInt(str0[i]);
    System.out.println(yearData[i]);
}
```

Comment: How is it not displaying an output? Is it running correctly... ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your input, what the output should be and what error or the current output that you get. Read this for guidance: [mcve]

Comment: Please show the input that you expect your program to be able to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is not working. Anyway consider the given example which is using **Regular Expression**, where you found all the numbers in the string, so our regular expression works well. By changing the Regular Expression you can get the substring as well as you can skip the head part. I hope it would help.

```
    String regEx = "[+|-]?(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?)|(\\.\\d+)";
    String str = "256 is the square of 16 and -2.5 squared is 6.25 “ + “and -.243 is less than 0.1234.";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
   Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
   int i = 0; 
   String subStr = null;
   while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
year = year.trim(); // This should come before the split()...
str0 = year.split("[\\s,;]+"); // split() uses RegEx...
int[] yearData = new int[str0.length-1];

for(i = 0; i < str0.length-1; i++) {
    yearData[i] = Integer.parseInt(str0[i]);
    System.out.println(yearData[i]);
}
```